# Incremental load >> Flatfile SSDT

Tags: ssis

I have made an incremental load, 
Only rows with a unique  ID will be added to the destination.
I want to also write out my inserts to a flat file

What would be the easiest way to do this?
[My data flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWAiL.png)

Comment: Can this be stated the following way... I want to also write out my inserts to a flat file? If so, then add a multicast between lookup and destination. A multicast duplicates the rows to multiple paths. And then one path to oleDB and one path to flatfile.

Comment: I see you updated question. My comment above is the best way to write to multiple deistinations

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments above, here is your data flow:

[image]